Argument Dependant Lookup and its impact on overloading operators for STL types
I have been bitten recently by ADL (Argument Dependant Lookup) similarly to this link. The consensus seems to be that operator overloading should always be done in one of the arguments' namespace to avoid this kind of issues.
However, with STL types, this is not an option since it is UB to write code in namespace std.
What would you do if you wanted to define for example a stream operator for std::list<int> ?

please make the question self contained, use links for additional information. What is "similarly to this link" ?

I would not define such an operator for exactly this reason. Stream formatting is on its way out anyway. Welcome your new std::format overlords.

Overloading operator<<() for stl containers and overloading << operator for c++ stl containers

I wouldnt implement an operator that has only std:: parameters in the first place. Its not only ADL, but it has other issues too

I would write a void print(const std::list<int>&) or just write a loop

My advice, don't write operators for types you do not own.  instead, write named functions.

Or wrap it in a type you do own. There is no problem with overloading << for a struct my_list_wrapper { const std::list<int>& ref; };

I would write a named function
void print(const std::list<int>&);

Or overload an operator<< for a type in my own namespace:
namespace my {
    struct list_wrapper {
        const std::list<int>& ref;
    };
    
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const list_wrapper&);
}

The function does not need ADL and the << for the custom type is totally fine with ADL.
Generally, I advice against overloading operators for types you do not own. Whatever you can do to types from std:: any other library could do as well. This is potential for conflict and problems.
